# What are the most important POSIX functions not available in Android?

Tags: android, c++, linux, android-ndk, posix

I'm about to port a large C++ project (some sort of Library Project, it contains absolutely no GUI) to Android. It's actually a Visual C++ project, but it will be ported to Linux as intermediate step. I know that Android is not a "full" Linux and does not claim to provide all POSIX functions, but I also know there are a lot of "POSIXish functions" on Android by using the NDK.

**Now my actual question is:**

Which are the biggest/most important functions that are NOT available on Android compared with the full POSIX set? So that I can keep that in mind when doing the porting from Visual C++ to Linux GCC.

I tried to find something on Google, but found nothing really helpful, just here and there some stuff that mentioned that there are some POSIX functions on Android...

Comment: perhaps this can help you - http://mobilepearls.com/labs/native-android-api/ and here some more insight -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10235403/porting-embedded-visual-c-code-to-android and here https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-ndk/xZES51OYakY

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4610086/pthread-cancel-alternatives-in-android-ndk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bionic a recode by Google. It is small but optimized for Android.

The only big thing I know of that it lacks is indeed the `pthread_cancel()` function.

My experience is that if you port it successfully to GNU/Linux, without `pthread_cancel()` calls, then you should be mostly ok.

BTW, what kind of library are you trying to build? What does it uses? Network, threads...

PS: Even Linux is not fully POSIX.

Answer (score 4):

**Bionic Wikipedia page**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bionic_(software)#Differences_from_POSIX

Also has some interesting info:

> Although bionic aims to implement all of C11 and POSIX, there are still (as of Oreo) about 70 POSIX functions missing[8] from libc. There are also POSIX functions such as the endpwent/getpwent/setpwent family that are inapplicable to Android because it lacks a passwd database. As of Oreo, libm is complete.
>
> Some functions deliberately do not conform to the POSIX or C standards for security reasons, such as printf which does not support the %n format string.[9]

**Official Bionic in tree documentation quote**

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/37ad9597839c70a7ec79578e5072df9c189fc830/docs/status.md

> Run ./libc/tools/check-symbols-glibc.py in bionic/ for the current list of POSIX functions implemented by glibc but not by bionic. Currently (2017-10):
>
> ```
> aio_cancel
> aio_error
> aio_fsync
> aio_read
> aio_return
> aio_suspend
> aio_write
> lio_listio
> pthread_cancel
> pthread_mutex_consistent
> pthread_mutex_getprioceiling
> pthread_mutex_setprioceiling
> pthread_mutexattr_getprioceiling
> pthread_mutexattr_getprotocol
> pthread_mutexattr_getrobust
> pthread_mutexattr_setprioceiling
> pthread_mutexattr_setprotocol
> pthread_mutexattr_setrobust
> pthread_setcancelstate
> pthread_setcanceltype
> pthread_testcancel
> wordexp
> wordfree
> libm
> ```
>
> Current libm symbols: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/master/libm/libm.map.txt
>
> 0 remaining missing POSIX libm functions.

Answer (score 2):

The most obvious feature missing is `pthread_cancel()`.

This blog has some additional details: http://codingrelic.geekhold.com/2008/11/six-million-dollar-libc.html

Good overview of Bionic: https://android-platform.googlegroups.com/attach/0f8eba5ecb95c6f4/OVERVIEW.TXT?gda=HWJaO0UAAAB1RXoVyyH5sRXFfLYnAq48KOFqr-45JqvtfiaR6gxIj4Qe8cBqW3BaWdSUPWi_jHqO3f1cykW9hbJ1ju6H3kglGu1iLHeqhw4ZZRj3RjJ_-A&view=1&part=4

Answer (score 2):

shared memory is also something you might find differently implemented in android. was hit hard while trying to work with shm_open and shm_unlink on android kernel. Android implements asynchronous shared memory (ashmem).

Comment: Yes, one has to call ashmem_create_region and share returned file descriptor between processes via binder to mmap it.