# error:undefined reference to 'pthread_testcancel' when compile with NDK

Tags: android, c, compilation, android-ndk

I have a third-party library written by C and I want to use it in my Android project by JNI.
The issue is that a error occured when I compile it like below:

> error: undefined reference to 'pthread_testcancel'

and the code is

```
#if !defined(WIN32) && !defined (WINCE) && !defined(ITRON) && !defined(BTRON) && !defined(TENGINE) && !defined(PROCESS_BASE)
  pthread_testcancel();
#endif
```

And only this method compile failed, some other methods are all ok like `pthread_kill`, `pthread_join`, `pthread_create`...

Anybody can help me to resolve it? Thanks very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android's NDK doesn't support `pthread_cancel` due to the complexity also [implementation of it is error prone and harmful to performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26823926/pthread-cancel-not-found-compiling-with-android-toolchain) (of all code). so you can have look on [`pthread_cancel()` alternatives in Android NDK.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4610086/pthread-cancel-alternatives-in-android-ndk)

Comment: Thank you. So may I delete it?
testcancel  just does a checking for if cancelable.